# Проблема с размещением выведенного в html php текста

Tags: php, html, css

У меня есть страница на html которая включает в себя возможности входа и регистрации через PHP.
У меня была необходимость вывести как текст имя параметра "user" на страницу index.php с помощью сессий.

По итогу, введёный пользователем логин отображается на главной странице, но по какой-то неизвестной мне причине всегда в левом верхнем углу. Я пробовал перемещать его через CSS, но ничего не вышло.

P.S основная задача поместить его ближе к правому углу страницы.
Как бы я не изменял значения "position", текст все равно остается на месте. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Собственно, сам код:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <?php 
        session_start();
        $userecho =  $_SESSION['user']; 
    ?>
    
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <style>
    body {
        background-image: url(/images/backgr.png);  
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: #000;
    }   
    </style>
    </head>
        <body class="back">
        <div class="div1"></div>

        <span class="test">
            <? echo $userecho; ?>
        </span>     
            
    </body> 
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
.test {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10%;
    right: -10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы задаете элементу `position: absolute`, то он позиционируется относительно родительского элемента, если у него так же задан `position`. В вашем коде родительским элементом является `body`, но у него не задан `position`. В таком случае расчет производится от краев окна браузера. Далее, вы `top` и `right` задаете в процентах с отрицательным значением. Просто укажите смещение в пикселях

```
.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 50px;
}
```